# Eigenvalues of matrix subtraction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the matrix A:

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I know that its eigenvalues are 0 (with Multiplicity of 7) and 8.
How can I easily find the eigenvalues of the Matrix: **T = 0.5I-$\mu$A**?
What is the relation between the original eigenvalues of **A** and **0.5I-$\mu$A**?

Comment: Write down the eigenvalue equation and re-arrange it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $\alpha A+\beta I$ are $\alpha\lambda+\beta$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.